# UICollectionView image load again and again with lagging in scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uicollectionview

```
#pragma mark Collection View
-(NSInteger )numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView {
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [array count];
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSLog(@"indexpath row : %d", indexPath.row);

    UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
    NSString *checkisfolder=[checkfolder objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *selectorValue=[list2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[imgarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    NSLog(@"indexpath image : %@", [imgarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);
    NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];

    // load image from JSON URL
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
                       UIImageView *imgView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 140, 80)] autorelease];

                       if (imgView != nil) {
                           NSLog(@"selectorValue1  : %@", selectorValue);

                           UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];

                           dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                               UIButton *imageButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
                               imageButton.frame = CGRectMake(15, 10, 257, 140);
                               [imageButton setImage:img forState:UIControlStateNormal];

                               imageButton.tag=[selectorValue intValue];

                               imageButton.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = NO;
                               if([checkisfolder  isEqual: @"isfolder"]){
                                   [imageButton addTarget:self action:@selector(imagefolderClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
                               }else{
                                   [imageButton addTarget:self action:@selector(imageViewClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
                               }
                               [cell addSubview:imageButton];

                               UILongPressGestureRecognizer *press = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(userLongPressed:)];

                               press.minimumPressDuration = 1.0;

                               [imageButton addGestureRecognizer:press];
                               [press release];
                           });
                       };
                   });


    label.text = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    label.numberOfLines = 0;

    [cell.layer setBorderWidth:1.0f];
    [cell.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor];
    [cell.layer setCornerRadius:5.0f];

    return cell;
}
```

The image is loaded again from the server and making scrolling up or down  very lag. The following is the log when this is happening.

```
2016-02-15 10:53:55.273 Go Test[2086:651177] indexpath row : 0
2016-02-15 10:53:55.274 Go Test[2086:651177] indexpath image : http://media.movideo.com/media-images-670/media/1358499/320x160.png
2016-02-15 10:53:55.465 Go Test[2086:651298] selectorValue1  : 475
2016-02-15 10:53:55.476 Go Test[2086:651177] indexpath row : 1
2016-02-15 10:53:55.476 Go Test[2086:651177] indexpath image : http://media.movideo.com/media-images-670/media/1358500/320x160.png
2016-02-15 10:53:55.534 Go Test[2086:651284] selectorValue1  : 476
2016-02-15 10:53:55.541 Go Test[2086:651177] indexpath row : 2
2016-02-15 10:53:55.542 Go Test[2086:651177] indexpath image : http://media.movideo.com/media-images-670/media/1358318/320x160.png
2016-02-15 10:53:55.709 Go Test[2086:651283] selectorValue1  : 477
2016-02-15 10:53:55.818 Go Test[2086:651177] there are 0 objects in the array
2016-02-15 10:53:55.819 Go Test[2086:651177] there are 0 objects in the array
```

How can I solve the lag problem? The image should be loaded from server once only and saved in cache or local.

Comment: I rewrite the code. Change `[imageButton setImage:img forState:UIControlStateNormal];` to `[imageButton setImageWithURL:url forState:UIControlStateNormal placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"logo.png"]];`. but I got this error `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIButton setImageWithURL:forState:placeholderImage:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x155ecf00'`.

Answer (score 1):

- you can use SDWebimage to solve the problem.
- The other way is to use dispatch_async/ NS Operation Queues.
- however SDWebImage does use one of the above methods internally. and would be advisable to be used as far as storing images are concerned.
- U need to cache the images.

Comment: @Pyro Thanks! Is there any tutorial how to rewrite the code ? I have already downloaded the SDWebimage framework and add line    #import "UIImageView+Webcache.h
to myviewcontroller class

Comment: `#import <SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h>`
followed by
`[self.Image sd_setImageWithURL:iurl placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@""]];`

Comment: Oh thx, but I have an `imgarray` that contain array of image url in the code. How should I rewrite?

Comment: `for(i=0 ; i<[imgarray count]; i++)

{

NSURL *iurl = imgarray[i];
[self.Image sd_setImageWithURL:iurl placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@""]];

}`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to cache image there are some great and popular third party frameworks are available which you can use like:

They can cache ans solve the lag problem

[SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage), 
[AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking)
and you may find some other better frameworks on github

If you want to maintain it manually you can use '**NSCache**' for which you can find some good tutorials on the internet

Comment: Thank you. I have an `imgarray` that contain array of image url in the code. How can I rewrite that?

Comment: You can iterate array of images in cellForItemAtIndexPath method with method of your choice like
  for SDWebImage imageview it will be like 

`code
NSURL *imgUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:[imgarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
  [imageButton sd_setImageWithURL:iurl placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@""]];`

For button: 
`code [imageButton sd_setImageWithURL:imgUrl  forState:UIControlStateNormal placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@""]]; `


or if you have array at single index  You can check Sharavan's response

Comment: Thx. I rewrite the code. Change `[imageButton setImage:img forState:UIControlStateNormal];` to `[imageButton setImageWithURL:url forState:UIControlStateNormal placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"logo.png"]];`. but I got this error `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIButton setImageWithURL:forState:placeholderImage:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x155ecf00'`.

Comment: You need to write `[imageButton sd_setImageWithURL:url forState:UIControlStateNormal placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"logo.png"]];` which is method of SDWebImage , you are writting `setImageWithUrl`  that method is not found any gives you error